# How can I add Lchild and Rchild to my existing nodes?

Tags: c, pointers, binary-search-tree

I have the following C program that adds Nodes to a tree and then the user can select a sorting method. How can I modify the program in a manner that will allow me to add a LChild and RChild to every node? Any help is highly appreciated since I am completely new to BSTs.

Writiong this because apparently my post is mostly code

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct treenode {
    struct treenode *lchild;
    struct treenode *rchild;
    int data;
    } *root = NULL;

void insertnode(struct treenode **pp,int d)
{
    for( ;*pp; )
    {
         if (d < (*pp)->data) pp = &(*pp)->lchild;
         else  pp = &(*pp)->rchild;
    }
    *pp = malloc (sizeof **pp);
    (*pp)->data = d;
    (*pp)->lchild = NULL;
    (*pp)->rchild = NULL;
}

void preorder(struct treenode *p)
{
    if(p==NULL)
    {
        printf("\nThe list is empty");
        return;
    }

    printf("%d,",p->data);
    if (p->lchild) preorder(p->lchild);
    if (p->rchild) preorder(p->rchild);
}

void postorder(struct treenode *p)
{
    if(p==NULL)
    {
        printf("\nThe list is empty");
        return;
    }

    if (p->lchild) preorder(p->lchild);
    if (p->rchild) preorder(p->rchild);
    printf("%d,",p->data);
}
void inorder(struct treenode *p)
{
    if(p==NULL)
    {
        printf("\nThe list is empty");
        return;
    }

    if (p->lchild) preorder(p->lchild);
    printf("%d,",p->data);
    if (p->rchild) preorder(p->rchild);
}

int main(void)
{
    root=NULL;
    int choice,data;

    while(1)
    {
     printf("\nPress 1 for inserting a node in BST fashion: ");
     printf("\nPress 2 for traversing the tree in preorder fashion :");
     printf("\nPress 3 for traversing the tree in postorder fashion :");
     printf("\nPress 4 for traversing the tree in inorder fashion :");
     printf("\nPress 5 to exit :");


     printf("\nEnter your choice: ");
     scanf("%d", &choice);

    switch(choice)
    {
    case 1: printf("\nEnter the data to be inserted:");
        scanf("%d",&data);
        insertnode( &root,data);

        break;

    case 2: preorder(root);
        break;

    case 3: postorder(root);
        break;

    case 4: inorder(root);
        break;

    case 5: exit(0);
        break;
    default: printf("\nYou have entered an invalid choice. Please try     again");
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when a new value added to BST,then it check the conditions such that if value ">" the current node value then its we move to the right child of the node and  if value "<" then we move to the left child of the node,we do this untill we get to leaf node.

As for your case,just change for condition with while conditions and check if it works.

```
void insertnode(struct treenode **pp,int d)
{
    while((*pp)->data == NULL)
    {
       if (d < (*pp)->data) 
         pp = &(*pp)->lchild;

       else  
         pp = &(*pp)->rchild;
    }
      *pp = malloc (sizeof **pp);
      (*pp)->data = d;
      (*pp)->lchild = NULL;
     (*pp)->rchild = NULL;
}
```

Comment: I get this error: [Error] request for member 'data' in something not a structure or union. It's for the condition of while

Comment: have you copied this code because it will create confusion for you understand try to write your own code

Comment: if I use the code you mentioned aboce my program crashes.